# Spring Boot - Security - How to add pre authentication rules in authentication workflow

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I am running a Spring Boot REST API secured with OAuth2.

Here's my actual working 100% configuration for require for an access token & refresh token:

```
@Configuration
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {        
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

I need now to add a pre authentication configuration, so login it's only available if some configuration it's available.

I'm confused if I need to override the `AuthenticationManager` or the `AuthenticationProvider`

I tried to add a CustomAuthenticationProvider like this in the same class above:

```
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    auth
        .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    // @formatter:on
}
```

And then:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (allowLogin()) {
            // Should call the UserDetailService as normally workflow.
            return null;
        }
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Out of service");
    }

    private boolean allowLogin() {
        //Custom logic            
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

But then when I throw the exception, my UserDetailService is triggered anyway. So this is not an option or maybe I am implementing in a wrong way.

What about implementing a CustomAuthenticationManager? I don't know where to call it.

I am trying to avoid throwing an exception in the `loadByUsername` method of the UserDetailService because if anybody has already got a token then he will be still available of consuming my API. Maybe I have to create the logic in both processes?

**UPDATED**

What I think that I need to do is to add a `CustomAccessDecisionVoter`, but don't know where to configure for the resource server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing a Custom userDetailsService decorating the current UserDetailsService and overriding the *loadUserByUsername* method and return UserDetails with an 'ANONYMOUS' Role and do not permit users with that role to your app

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserDetails user = userRolesManager.loadUserByUsername(username);
    if(allowLogin()){
        return user;
    }else{
        return new User(username, "notUsed", true, true,true,true, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if you are already logged in? Remember I'm using Oauth2, so if you have a token, you would not go through that method again...

Comment: i have not much experience in OAuth. But i'm guessing a filter is what you will need. Something like [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configurers/AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.html)

Comment: @FernandoFradegrada: AFAIK your custom `UserDetailsService` is only called, if your custom `AuthenticationProvider` is called. So it makes no difference, where you implement the `Exception`. In both cases you are still able to use your OAuth2 token.

Comment: So there's my problem. I need to grant access only between and scheduled time window. For example "you only can login or access resources from 9 a.m to 9 p.m and I going mad on how to implement that..